# Error when using REST URL

Tags: rest

Hello we can use foll URL in IE and get XML output:

```
http://intranet:1111/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties/PictureUrl
```

But if we try to use the below URL we get error as feed format not supported. What is reason?

```
http://intranet:1111/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a problem with your REST url, rather a setting you need to change in IE.  Go to Options > Content Tab > Settings.  Uncheck `Turn on feed reading view`.  See this blog for visuals: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/feed-format-not-supported-when-trying-to-access-the-site-col/

Also, Chrome has some apps that allow you to view REST responses, and format them in either JSON or Atom.  You just need to sign in to your SharePoint site in the Chrome browser to authenticate.  I find it easier than reading in IE.

Comment: Hi thanks for answer. One quick question:- when we enter the URL number 1, then we get a response in browser. Is that XML or is it JSOM? Confused..

Comment: In IE? That's XML.  In order to get JSON you need to add the following header: `"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"`.  You cannot do that in IE, however.  I use this [Chrome app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo)